# After repelling the Citadel attack, can I complete quests where the quest giver is missing?

Tags: mass-effect-3

After repelling the Citadel attack, I am unable to find Barla Von and Sellea in Presidium Commons to return their respective quests. Am I too late to ever turn these quests in, or will the quest givers eventually return? If so, when?

Comment: If you look in the bank where Barla Von used to be, you'll find the wall was swept with bullets. It doesn't look good for the little guy.

Comment: Can definitely confirm that Barla Von caught a few not so stray bullets. So, the little guy is gone and that mission a dud :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been unable to locate Barla Von. After completing Priority: Citadel (third iteration, where you meet with the Asari councilor), the quest has become grey, indicating that it is no longer possible to complete. I conclude that Citadel: Barla Von cannot be turned in after the Citadel attack.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for both of them too after the Citadel attack,
but I finally found Sellea and he's not where I would have expected him to be.

While the map shows that he's in the Courtyard (4),
I actually found him right outside of the C-Sec Outpost (5).

Comment: Thanks, I found him! Looking at your username I'm guessing Barla Von is still missing. Have you progressed in the plot much after the Citadel attack?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that there is virtually NO WAY to complete those side quests after the Cerberus Attack on the Citadel.

Very annoying, especially when they have been completed and all you need to do is talk to a few people.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. I too had about 3-4 Citadel side/mini quests to finish or turn in but when I repelled the Cerberus attack on the Citadel most, if not all, the people were gone.

The ones I missed were:

- Find Terminal for the Hanar
- Find the one guy's son (left of elevator on embassy flow)
- Barla Von one
- increasing power unit for Citadel (I think)

This should not effect too many or any achievements.