# Where is Kasumi after the Citadel mission?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Near the start of the game, I was working on (but did not finish yet) the Hanar mission with Kasumi (she cloaks and follows you).

I then completed the

> defend Citadel story mission

and I cannot find Kasumi anymore.

What happened to her? What's her status? Where is she?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54059/after-repelling-the-citadel-attack-can-i-complete-quests-where-the-quest-giver/54543#54543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quest is apparently abandoned (if you do not complete it yet) after that Citadel mission (gets marked as complete) and BioWare completely writes out Kasumi from the game with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

She should be in you list of war assets.

Comment: She is not, I never completed the mission yet.

Comment: She will be after you complete it, then.

Comment: The mission does not show up available on my journal.

Comment: How many of the consoles have you found?  You just may need to find the next console to pick up the quest again.   Check your journal.  If the quest is greyed out you may have missed the chance to complete it.  There are a couple of quests that can become un-completable after the Citadel Attack.

Comment: Right, if I missed the chance to complete it... that's my question. So where is Kasumi now in the galaxy? My question isn't about the mission or if she's under my war assets or not.

Comment: If you didn't complete the mission, she won't become a war asset which is how she's represented for the rest of the game.  My guess is that you missed your opportunity, and you won't run into her for the rest of the game.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to find Kasumi again to complete the mission. Just pick up where you left off in the quest and it will progress normally.

[This page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Hanar_Diplomat) provides a walkthrough of this specific quest. You should be able to find where you left off and resume from there.

Comment: I'm not asking how to complete the mission. I'm asking where Kasumi is; the mission is marked as no longer active for me...

Comment: Fair enough, but she may reappear when you start making progress on her related quest. Have you tried talking to Bau outside Commander Bailey's office side the human embassy? Or, if that doesn't work, try heading over to the Spectre Terminal and select the "Hanar Embassy Tracking" option, if it's available.

Comment: Indeed, I'm just looking for a specific answer and not possibilities.

Comment: It *may* be bugged -- if you start a citadel sidequest, then leave the citadel before you finish, the waypoint vanishes.