# Where can I find the Cerberus Turian Poison?

Tags: mass-effect-3

My galaxy is currently 100% scanned and I haven't found any sign of a sample of Cerberus Turian Poison. Is it located in a galaxy I just haven't unlocked yet? Or perhaps in the Priority missions I'm waiting to do?

Considering how [some missions become impossible to complete](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54059/after-repelling-the-citadel-attack-can-i-complete-quests-where-the-quest-giver) after certain Priority missions sometimes, I'm trying to put off the ones I have (Eden Prime and Perseus Veil) until absolutely necessary.

Comment: Just a note: Eden Prime is the From Ashes DLC. Doing it won't lock out anything, and doing it sooner means more Jacik dialog. Go do it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a side mission you'll undertake to rescue some Cerberus scientists who have defected.  This mission is titled "Arrae: Ex-Cerberus Scientists."  I don't want to spoil it, but it's a side mission that can potentially involve one of your former Mass Effect 2 squadmates.

During one part of this mission, you'll be able to wander around their lab.  The data about the poison is located in their lab.  I believe it's on the second floor, in a corner away from the large plate glass windows.  There's an NPC that you'll have to talk to in order to progress the story, and I believe you should search the lab thoroughly first, lest you miss this item.

There's a second opportunity, near the end of the mission, where the same NPC will ask you if you're ready to leave or not.  I told this person I was ready immediately, but MBraedley confirms that if you want a second chance to check the lab, this is it.

Although I found it in the lab, the ME Wikia states that if you miss it, [you can buy it on the Citadel afterwards.](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Cerberus_Turian_Poison)  The credit reward for the mission is the same as the cost of the item, so if you missed it, the only reward is +5 Reputation, 30 XP, and a small War Asset boost from the general you cure.

Comment: I can confirm the second chance.  I totally missed the poison the first time I walked through the lab.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the necessary item called the Turian Toxin Data in the lab area (under a microscope) during the mission Arrae: Ex-Cerberus Scientists. If you already missed this item, you can buy it from the Spectre terminal.