# Who wants my Turian Toxin Data?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I picked up some "Turian Toxin Data" from a lab on the planet Gellix during the mission "Arrae: Ex-Cerberus Scientists." I'm assuming there's a quest out there in which someone actually wants this noxious stuff.

**To whom do I bequeath my newly-acquired jar of Turian Toxin Data and where is said person located?**

In laymen's terms, who wants this stuff and where are they?

Comment: some doctor in the hospital, don't have exact name or location, so will just leave comment

Comment: Related question with the opposite problem that you have: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55926/where-can-i-find-the-cerberus-turian-poison

Comment: I noticed that question when I pre-searched for duplicate questions of this question, but it actually doesn't help me out with what I'm looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: @johnjon - I did also answer your question for a reason.  I'm simply putting that in the comments as it IS related and crosslinking is always good for search indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for an assignment on the Citadel - there's a doctor in Huerta Memorial Hospital who wants it.  You should be able to complete it straight away.  [More details at the Mass Effect wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel:_Cerberus_Turian_Poison).

Answer (score 1):

There is a doctor in Huerta Memorial Hospital that can be overheard talking that he is lacking the ability to counteract a specific turian toxin. That is the doctor that is seeking this toxin that you have found.